# How to avoid redundant property for view model

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm

I have an interface from which my model and viewmodel implement.I have a list property in interface which model implements as list but for some reasons I need to use observable collection in view model.How can I implement same property with use of observable collection.Here is my sample code,

```
public  class MyObject
{
    public string Property1 { get; set; }
     public string Property1 { get; set; }
}

public interface IFoo
{
    List<MyObject> MyList { get; set; }
}


public class Model : IFoo
{
    private List<MyObject> mMyList;

    public List<MyObject> MyList
    {
        get { return mMyList; }
        set { mMyList = value; }
    }
}

public class ViewModel : IFoo
{

    // I want 
    //ObservableCollection<string> Mylist 
    //for view purpose,How can I use the same property from interface 


}
```

Comment: Have you looked at `CollectionView` as an alternative to `ObservableCollection`? Why is the model not implementing ObservableCollection?

Comment: How about changing the `IFoo.MyList` to an `ICollection<T>` instead (i.e. a contract) and leave the implementation to the implementors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stop being so demanding. In your interfaces, I mean.

```
public interface IFoo
{
    IList<MyObject> MyList { get; set; }
}
```

And use an OC behind the scenes

ObservableCollection implements IList, so you can easily

```
public class Bar : IFoo
{
    public IList<MyObject> MyList {get; private set;}
    public Bar()
    {
        MyList = new ObservableCollection<MyObject>();   
    //snip
```

The Binding will know our secret and act accordingly.

Comment: It gives an error that Bar doesnt implement MyList,correct type should be Generic.IList

Comment: @TRS no, it doesn't.  If you paste the actual error I might be able to straighten you out...

Comment: NVM.  Here--we'll call it an IList, but it'll actually be an OC (and will behave as expected).